# Can I get a list of all transactions that are sent to a particular contract on Eris?

Tags: transactions, eris-industries

Can I get a list of all transactions that are sent to a particular contract on Eris?

I see that there's a similar solution for the Ethereum API. 
[How can I get a list of of transaction data which are sent to a specific contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-of-transaction-data-which-are-sent-to-a-specific-contrac)

I'm hoping there's one for Eris.